# Error -fnested-function while compiling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I saw some documentation and previous questions about this, but couln't find a solution. My code looks like:

```
for(NSString str : NSArray){
    NSLog(str);
}
```

The error is at the :

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something along the lines of the following:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
for (NSString *str in myArray) 
{
   NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

Note the different syntax for the loop, and using the array object, not the class name there.  You can read about [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html) in the documentation.